# SSH and SCP commands fail to execute after successful SSH key authentification with error message: Win32 error 1114

Tags: python, linux, ssh, cygwin, mobaxterm

I am trying to automate file transfers from Linux on an Odroid XU4 (Linux) to my computer on windows.

I can authenticate with an SSH key to my windows machine and even get access to the MobaXterm terminal from my Odroid but when I try to send an ssh or scp command such as `ssh User@IP [command]` or `scp [file] User@IP:[destination]` I get the following error:

> 1 [main] sshd 11572 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bsh\usr\sbin\sshd.exe: *** fatal error - unable to load C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll, Win32 error 1114

I do not understand where this is coming from for the following reasons:

- ***It worked before*** I try managing the SSH connection and commands with Python.
- ***It works with Raspbian*** on my Raspberry Pi, even after I started getting the error. I thought that maybe I had inadvertently modified something on my cygwin configuration but the fact that I can still connect and send commands via the RP says otherwise.

I am still quite new to making SSH/SCP communication protocols, could it be that I modified the "channel" which is used to access the remote host? Has anyone came across and overcame this issue?

The only documentation I found on this bug is related to cygwin but they are all over 5 years old and use Windows Server 2003, [1](https://cygwin.cygwin.narkive.com/74Q2r1Mn/openssh-fatal-error-unable-to-load-c-windows-system32-user32-dll-win32-error-1114), [2](https://cygwin.cygwin.narkive.com/mOGWxduv/cygwin-sshd-dumping-stack-trace-when-not-allocating-pseudo-tty). Some suggest adding permissions following [this](http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/~kscully/CygwinSSHD_W2K3.html), but I already have them so I'm running out of ideas on how to debug this.

I am joining my configuration and the full callback of this error underneath. As well as what I tried on Python before everything breaks. Let me know if you need more information.

---

**My setup:**

---

**Local host: Odroid XU4 - Linux**

- Ubuntu LTS 18.04
- Architecture: arm7l
- OpenSSH_7.6p1
- Python 3.6

**Remote host: Windows 10 - 64 bits**

- MobaXterm
- Cygwin

---

**Python**

---

On python, I used the **Paramiko** and **scp** libraries. I tried the following commands:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient 
from scp import SCPClient

ssh=SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect(hostname, username=USER)
```

This made me connect successfully. Then I tried two ways of sending a file over via paramiko and scp. From there I started to get the error and now, even when I use the terminal to send the commands, I get the error above.

```
os.system('scp dir/test.png USER@IP:"/cygdrive/c/Users/USER/Box/"')
```

and with scp:

```
def progress(filename, size, sent):
    sys.stdout.write("%s\'s progress: %.2f%%   \r" % (filename, float(sent)/float(size)*100))

scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport(), progress=progress)
scp.put(local_file, remote_destination)
```

---

**Full Callback**

---

> odroid@odroid:~$ scp -v dir/test.png 
>  USER@IP:"/cygdrive/c/Users/USER/Box/" 
>   Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host IP, user USER, command scp -v -t /cygdrive/c/Users/USER/Box/ 
>   OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017 
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
>   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * 
>   debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port 22. 
>   debug1: Connection established. 
>   debug1: identity file /home/odroid/.ssh/id_rsa type 0 
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
>   debug1: identity file /home/odroid/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
>   debug1: identity file /home/odroid/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
>   debug1: identity file /home/odroid/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
>   debug1: identity file /home/odroid/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
>   debug1: identity file /home/odroid/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
>   debug1: identity file /home/odroid/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
>   debug1: identity file /home/odroid/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1 
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000 
>   debug1: Authenticating to IP:22 as 'USER' 
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received 
>   debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org 
>   debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
>   debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none 
>   debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none 
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 
>   debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
>   SHA256: ksdJSQNSèsQ987S8SKHGSJBSQqshdfqf87kjj 
>   debug1: Host 'IP' is known and matches the ECDSA host key. 
>   debug1: Found key in /home/odroid/.ssh/known_hosts:1 
>   debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks 
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS 
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
>   debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks 
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive 
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Offering public key: RSA 
>   SHA256:JBSQqshdfqf87kjj/fqf87kjjG2EGCSQqshhDsd /home/odroid/.ssh/id_rsa 
>   debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279 
>   debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
>   Authenticated to IP ([IP]:22). 
>   debug1: channel 0: new [client-session] 
>   debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com 
>   debug1: Entering interactive session. 
>   debug1: pledge: network 
>   debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0 
>   debug1: Sending environment. 
>   debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /cygdrive/c/Users/USER/ 
>         1 [main] sshd 13224 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bsh\usr\sbin\sshd.exe: *** fatal error - unable to load C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll, Win32 error 1114
>   debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0 
>   debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0 
>   debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1 
>   debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK 
>   debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK 
>   Transferred: sent 2748, received 2932 bytes, in 0.3 seconds 
>   Bytes per second: sent 9984.6, received 10653.1 
>   debug1: Exit status -1 
>   lost connection

Answer (score 0):

The fatal error is not due to cygwin sshd but to the W10 one as mentioned in the 
error message:

> C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bsh\usr\sbin\sshd.exe

The Cygwin one is installed under

```
$ cygpath -w /usr/sbin/sshd.exe
C:\cygwin64\usr\sbin\sshd.exe
```

To use the Cgwin sshd you need to remove or disable the W10 one as service 
and enable the Cygwin one.

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-06/msg00276.html

Comment: That is strange because there is supposedly no Windows sshd service installed on my machine (disabled by my company). 
When I run:
    `$ cygrunsrv -R sshd` 
I get:

> cygrunsrv: Error removing a service: OpenService:  Win32 error 1060:
> The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

I did find the sshd.exe in the path you mentioned. I tried remonving it manually but I got:

> sssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

So I put it pack and got my original error again.
Maybe there is something in the mail I didn't do correctly.

Comment: Is Cygwin even necessary if ssh comes with Windows 10?

Comment: @motorbaby, maybe not on regular windows but I am working on a company laptop and my company deactivates all windows services, Windows OpenSSH included. That's why I'm using Cygwin with MobaXterm to create my server on Windows 10. If you know another way to do it I'm open to trying it out!

Comment: @Dee I'm having trouble with SCP but not SSH, hence finding your question. I'm wondering in your case if trying a different port may resolve your issue. See https://www.ssh.com/ssh/port